# Scrollable Menu Section with Buttons

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I'm attempting to create a menu that you can scroll left and right on that only takes up a section of the page. Here is a simple sample of that:

[image: Sample]

The everything below the top bar and the top of the pagecontrol move left and right. I attempted to use a pageviewcontroller but all of the tutorials I've found use it with static objects. If any buttons are used, they are used outside the pageviewcontroller.

My question is if there is something like the pageviewcontroller that I can place buttons on which scrolls left and right in the same manner?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would follow one of two possible ways:

1) Creation of **pageViewController** with designed individual pages of pageViewController, that have properly designed layout, i.e. centering and optimizing sizes of buttons etc.

2) Creating of **UICollectionView**, that uses horizontal pagination. Some solutions are described here:

[UICollectionView with Paging Enable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24303883/uicollectionview-with-paging-enable)

Comment: I tried the first option and it has paging left and right but I'm unable to do anything with the buttons.

Answer (score 1):

In your particular example I think it would be better to use UICollectionView with UIPageControl (you'll need to compute when you have to change current page in collection view scroll delegate method scrollViewDidScroll or scrollViewDidEndDecelerating).

Something like this:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    NSInteger currentIndex = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
    // change page
}
```